# Google Docs using multiple manual criterion in DSUM

Tags: google-docs

How can I manually enter multiple criterion into a DSUM function?

I can have it check a single set of criterion with: `=DSUM(J3:L55, "Charge", {"Category";"Coffee"})`

However changing that to `=DSUM(J3:L55, "Charge", {"Category";"Coffee";"Split";"Yes"}` Causes it to just use the `"Category";"Coffee"` but and ignore the `;"Split";"Yes"` section.

What is the syntax to set multiple criterion in google docs? I cannot really make a 2x2 table to each category I have (`=DSUM(J3:L55, "Charge", D7:E8)` ) and instead need to just manually enter the criterion.

[image: DSUM with table criterion is in blue]

DSUM with table criterion is in blue. I am selecting "Category" though "Split?" and want to use both Category and Split as criterion without having to resort to the darker blue table you see there

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

`=DSUM(J3:L55, "Charge", {{"Category";"Coffee"},{"Split";"Yes"}})`

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. This is the correct syntax. This is a really old question and I have long since figured out how to do this, just on a different spreadsheet.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer doesn't work in all languages. The other syntax pointed out in other answers (using `\`) works in every language.

Comment: In portuguese, testing and failing with the answers below, I got it to work like this:
`=DSUM(J3:L55; "Charge"; {{"Category";"Coffee"}\{"Split";"Yes"}})`
May work in other latin languages.

Comment: User @Keybonesabi is right. Do NOT use this notation, instead use his.

Comment: What's the difference between the `;` and the `,` ?

Comment: Cody, in the old method
';' Separated the test titles from the associated values (Rows)
',' Separated the titles and test values (Columns)
=DSUM(TestTitle1,TestTitle2;TestValue1,TestValue2)

Answer (score 9):

Google updated the DSUM function. The update **requires** you to specify an **array/table** for criterion.
Where Column names and Criterion were named before, you now reference a table:
    `{F3,G4}`
Where
 "F3" and "G3" are the column names to be referenced.
 "F4" and "G4" are the Test Values.
 "F3" is Category
 "G3" is Split?
 "F4" is Coffee
 "G4" is Yes
An example of the new formula is:
    `=DSUM(A1:E55, "Charge", {F3:G4})`
I think this makes it easier to update the table and reference changes.
You can have multiple criteria, I tested it with "Equipment" and "Yes" by adding another row to my criterion table.

> **Reference:** [Google Help: DSUM()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094281?hl=en)

**The Old Way:**
The correct syntax is to use commas to separate the columns.
    `{"Category","Split";"Coffee","Yes"}`
    `{ Column1  , Column2 ; Test 1 , Test 2}`
so your formula should be
    `=DSUM(J3:L55, "Charge", {"Category","Split";"Coffee","Yes"})`

Comment: After reviewing my code, it appears there is a change to how Google Sheets runs DSUM.

Answer (score 8):

In languages that use `,` as the decimal separator, you cannot use `,` for separating values. Use a backslash `\` instead. So your formula should then be

```
=DSUM(J3:L55; "Charge"; {"Category"\"Split";"Coffee"\"Yes"})
```

Comment: Reviewer's comment: That seems a great first answer, although I don't see the relation between your solution and Turkish ...

Comment: my answer is for Turkish users, because in Turkish format of google spreadsheets, you can't use "," char as separator in formulas. It is used for decimal point, so google recommend using "\" char instead of ","

Answer (score 5):

Same if you are using French format. You can not use `,`. Your formula should be

```
=DSUM(J3:L55; "Charge"; {"Category"\"Split";"Coffee"\"Yes"})
```

Maybe the same for other Latin laguages too

Answer (score 0):

When you do d7:e8, it'll iterate on columns first and lines later. So on your example, you would have "Category", "Split?" (1st line) and "Coffee","Yes" (2nd line).

So, instead of {"Category";"Coffee";"Split";"Yes"} you should use {"Category";"Split";"Coffee";"Yes"}.